# fakebold error in fontspec or lualatex

Tags: fontspec, luatex

I have been trying to fake small caps which are not available in Myriad Pro. So I used the Scale and FakeBold options. Scaling is allright, but as you all know the glyphs slim out. To work against that I tried to "fatten" them somewhat.

The code below does not "fatten" the scaled characters when using lualatex (latest TeX-Live). Using xelatex (also latest TeX-Live) works fine.

I think its a bug.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\begin{document}
ABC {\fontspec[FakeBold=5,Scale=0.72]{TeX Gyre Heros} ABC} ABC
\end{document}
```

For demonstration the code above uses another fontwich actually supports small caps.

Comment: I can only confirm the behavior.

Answer (score 15):

LuaTeX does not support emboldening, so `FakeBold` will not work. `fontspec` should issue a warning here.

It might be possible to implement emboldening in lua, say in `luaotfload` package, but I didn't investigate closely.

Here is a work around using pdf literals (which is essentially what XeTeX does behind the scenes).

```
\def\embolden#1#2{%
    \pdfliteral direct {2 Tr #1 w}%
     #2%
    \pdfliteral direct {0 Tr 0 w}%
}
ABC \embolden{0.5}{ABC} ABC
\bye
```

This even works with pdftex.

(Note, when you use `Scale=0.72`, the `FakeBold` will be `5*0.72`, so you might want to use `0.36` instead of `0.5`)

---

With the advent of LuaTeX 0.95.0 the `\pdf...` primitives have been moved to the unified `\pdfextension` interface.  The above code does not work anymore and has to be modified to reflect these changes.

```
\def\embolden#1#2{%
    \pdfextension literal direct {2 Tr #1 w}%
     #2%
    \pdfextension literal direct {0 Tr 0 w}%
}
ABC \embolden{0.5}{ABC} ABC
\bye
```

Alternatively one could define `\pdfliteral` as devised in the [LuaTeX manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/doc/luatex/luatex.pdf):

```
\protected\def\pdfliteral{\pdfextension literal}
```

Comment: Works fine, twiddling with Scale and "enbolden" I get an fake "small caps" thats close enough to the real thing.

Comment: Hm when trying this I can easily twiddle up the "enbolden" factor up to very thick but I can not get it low enough. Even when I set it to 0.0 it comes out too black for me. Both in print and on screen it still looks like ink blobs to me. I suppose the technique used is not very compatible with my font...

Comment: This is 4 yars old question..Lualatex supports fakeslant..does it support fakebold now? i tryied and with no succes..maybe my lualatex engine is too old?

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili: Per Henri Menke’s comment here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/397480/75284 the fakebold in LuaTeX will come eventually, but not soon.