# LuaLaTeX: Using a custom command in a font size range

Tags: luatex, fontspec, fontsize

My problem is that the fonts I want to use don't have optical sizes or medium cuts available and the slimming of hairlines at small text sizes disturbs me. Since the fake boldening of `fontspec` doesn't work with `lualatex`, I've settled with the technique described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34290/75284

A MWE:

```
% !TEX program = lualatex

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\newcommand\optsize[1]{%
    \pdfextension literal direct {2 Tr 0.15 w}%
     #1%
    \pdfextension literal direct {0 Tr 0 w}%
}

\begin{document}
R\textsubscript{R} R\textsubscript{\optsize{R}}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

**My question:** Is there a way of using this custom command for a certain font size range automatically? E.g. `fontspec` provides this:

```
UprightFeatures={
    SizeFeatures={
        {Size={-9},Font=Normalfont},
        {Size={9-},Font=SmallTextFont}
    }
}
```

but I couldn't find a way to inject my custom command there to be used. Maybe there is another way using the lua backend.

Comment: Fake bold will probably arrive in LuaTeX 1.08 or 1.09 (i.e. not before TeX Live 2019 unfortunately). https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2018/091131.html